# Checkboxes and Radio Buttons not rendering properly in Angular 6/PrimeNg 6

Tags: angular, user-interface, primeng, angular6

**Current behavior**
Upgraded from Angular 5.2.6 => 6.0.4 and primeng 5.2.4 => 6.0.0-beta.1.  While the checkboxes and radio buttons still render, select, and highlight, they fail to render the actual check within the box when selected, or the dot within the radio button when selected.  This was tested in `Firefox 60.0.1 (64-bit)`, `Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0`,  and `Chrome 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.  No console errors are shown in the process of selecting (or deselecting in the case of the checkbox).

**Expected behavior**
I expect to see the checkbox and the dot of the radio button rendered.

**Minimal reproduction of the problem with instructions**
Create a checkbox or radio button in Angular 6.0.4 with primeng 6.0.0-beta.1 and check the box or make a selection to see that the check and/or dot are not being rendered.

**environment:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 8.9.4
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.4
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Is anyone else experiencing this behavior and/or knows of a workaround?  Thank you.

Note: originally posted here https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/5883 , but seeking a possible short-term solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's your answer:
[PrimeNG 6.0.0-beta.1 Released with PrimeIcons](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-6-0-0-beta-1-released-primeicons/)

Basically, do the following:

```
npm install primeicons --save
```

Then add the path to your styles in angular.json

```
"styles": [
              "node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.css",
              "node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

Comment: Thank you @Flat Badger, that is good to know and has been added in.  Unfortunately, it only partially resolved the issue as checkboxes now work, but radio buttons still do not.  Are you aware of icons still missing?

Comment: I can see the reference to the glyph in the class:
`.pi-circle-on:before { content: "\e911";}`
and I can see the glyph is supposedly there `<glyph unicode="&#xe911;" glyph-name="circle-on" data-tags="radio-on" d="M853.333 448c0-188.513-152.82-341.333-341.333-341.333s-341.333 152.82-341.333 341.333c0 188.513 152.82 341.333 341.333 341.333s341.333-152.82 341.333-341.333z" />`

So it should work, but it isn't picking it up for some reason (despite the fact that checkboxes are now functional).

Comment: If you go here: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/radiobutton the radiobuttons don't fill there either.  Perhaps this is intended?  If it is, I think it is a terrible idea, but maybe my radio buttons are working just fine; it's just that they made a glyph without a center in it.

Comment: Arrows are missing from the dropdowns too, until `node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css` is added to styles. Did you find this in PrimeNG's documentation anywhere? I couldn't. I had to figure this out the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the radio button was not working because I was using PrimeNg's Ultima theme and there was a sass file class that was negatively affecting the new PrimeIcons.  This was resolved by updating the sass resources with the newly-released Ultima 6.0.